# Whats app encryption

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Is the encryption automatically turned on or do i have to physically tap it to turn it on? I have sent some inappropriate messages to one of my contacts on Whats app and don't want ANYONE to see it. I cant remember if I turned on the encryption physically and I am afraid that that contact may show the messages to the wrong people or that someone can access the messages from another device or app

Comment: WhatsApp's encryption protocol just protects the messages while they are in transit. Once a message is received, it is decrypted and stored as plaintext. Furthermore, encryption does not prevent your contact to "show" that conversation to third parties.

Answer (score 1):

Encryption is always activated as long as both of you are using latest version of WhatsApp and there is no way to turn if off too.

You can also verify the encryption from "Verify security code" screen in the contact info screen.

Source: https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/28030015